# VB code not storing data in clipboard not working as expected

Tags: vb.net, clipboard

I have code that copies some HTML text into the clipboard. In my `ClipBoard.ContainsData(DataFormats.Html)` it shows True, but when I actually try and paste stuff, it shows a blank( though it gives me the option of pasting with formatting!). It's an aspx page here.

Code on Load of page:

```
Dim ThreadA As Thread
ThreadA = New Thread(AddressOf Me.MyAsyncTask)
ThreadA.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
'ThreadA.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA
ThreadA.Start()
```

Code on MyAsyncTask:

```
obj = New DataObject()
    obj.SetData(DataFormats.Html, True, "<a href='#'>abcd</a>")
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(obj, True)
```

I intend to also copy an image later with the HTML onto the ClipBoard.

EDIT: I have succeeded in copying an image, and I can copy plaintext. What I need is only a solution for copying formatted text, ie: to retain the formatting

Answer (score 0):

```
'Clipboard.SetDataObject(obj, True)'
```

To

'obj.Copy()'

also you may need 'Clipboard' inside the perenthesis depending on your version

hope this helps

Comment: obj has no method named 'Copy()'